# Error registering Avro schema: Register schema operation failed while writing to the Kafka store; error code: 50001

Tags: apache-kafka, avro, apache-kafka-streams, confluent-schema-registry

I have a weird issue to send an object that generated from the .avsc file.
On my local, there is no problem but on the dev server, it throws an exception when
I use producer to send this type of record to any topic or the streaming app to forward to a topic.
This type of object already consumes by many other apps.

thanks,

Austin

```java
Error registering Avro schema: Register schema operation failed while writing to the Kafka store; error code: 50001
Caused by: io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.exceptions.RestClientException: Register schema operation failed while writing to the Kafka store; error code: 50001
{
  "type": "record",
  "name": "object-name",
  "namespace": "com.compnay.schemas.java",
  "fields": [
    {
      "name": "message_type",
      "type": [
        "null",
        "int"
      ],
      "default": null
    },
    {
      "name": "repeat",
      "type": [
        "null",
        "int"
      ],
      "default": null
    },
    {
      "name": "scaled",
      "type": [
        "null",
        "string"
      ],
      "default": null
    },
    {
      "name": "turn",
      "type": [
        "null",
        "int"
      ],
      "default": null
    },
    {
      "name": "speed",
      "type": [
        "null",
        "double"
      ],
      "default": null
    },
    {
      "name": "second",
      "type": [
        "null",
        "int"
      ],
      "default": null
    },
    {
      "name": "maneuver",
      "type": [
        "null",
        "int"
      ],
      "default": null
    },
    {
      "name": "radio",
      "type": [
        "null",
        "int"
      ],
      "default": null
    },
    {
      "name": "source_id",
      "type": [
        "null",
        "string"
      ],
      "default": null
    },
    {
      "name": "status",
      "type": [
        "null",
        "int"
      ],
      "default": null
    }
  ]
}

Caused by: io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.exceptions.RestClientException: Register schema operation failed while writing to the Kafka store; error code: 50001
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.sendHttpRequest(RestService.java:209)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.httpRequest(RestService.java:235)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.registerSchema(RestService.java:326)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.registerSchema(RestService.java:318)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.registerSchema(RestService.java:313)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.CachedSchemaRegistryClient.registerAndGetId(CachedSchemaRegistryClient.java:119)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.CachedSchemaRegistryClient.register(CachedSchemaRegistryClient.java:156)
    at io.confluent.kafka.serializers.AbstractKafkaAvroSerializer.serializeImpl(AbstractKafkaAvroSerializer.java:79)
    at io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroSerializer.serialize(KafkaAvroSerializer.java:53)
    at io.confluent.kafka.streams.serdes.avro.SpecificAvroSerializer.serialize(SpecificAvroSerializer.java:65)
    at io.confluent.kafka.streams.serdes.avro.SpecificAvroSerializer.serialize(SpecificAvroSerializer.java:38)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serializer.serialize(Serializer.java:60)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.RecordCollectorImpl.send(RecordCollectorImpl.java:157)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.RecordCollectorImpl.send(RecordCollectorImpl.java:101)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.SinkNode.process(SinkNode.java:89)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:146)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:129)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:93)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.internals.KStreamMap$KStreamMapProcessor.process(KStreamMap.java:42)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorNode.process(ProcessorNode.java:117)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:146)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:129)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:93)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.internals.KStreamPassThrough$KStreamPassThroughProcessor.process(KStreamPassThrough.java:33)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorNode.process(ProcessorNode.java:117)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:146)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:125)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.internals.KStreamBranch$KStreamBranchProcessor.process(KStreamBranch.java:48)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorNode.process(ProcessorNode.java:117)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:146)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:129)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:93)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.SourceNode.process(SourceNode.java:84)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamTask.process(StreamTask.java:351)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.AssignedStreamsTasks.process(AssignedStreamsTasks.java:104)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.TaskManager.process(TaskManager.java:413)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runOnce(StreamThread.java:862)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runLoop(StreamThread.java:777)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.run(StreamThread.java:747)
```

Comment: It's seems to be a server side error in Schema Registry: https://docs.confluent.io/current/schema-registry/develop/api.html -- I would recommend to look into the Schema Registry logs to get more information.

Comment: the log in empty:

VM settings:
    Max. Heap Size (Estimated): 13.91G
    Ergonomics Machine Class: server
    Using VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM
I need to talk to admin people to enable logging

Answer (score 0):

your record has a dash in the name: `object-name`.
the [avro specification disallows this](https://avro.apache.org/docs/current/spec.html#names). legal names are basically the same as java legal names. specifically: `start with [A-Za-z_] subsequently contain only [A-Za-z0-9_]`